# How to get value range of system-variable sy-dbsys

Tags: abap

In ABAP I can use the system variable sy-dbsys to find out which database is running underneath my ABAP system, could be e.g. 'HDB' for HANA or 'Oracle'.

Is there a list of all potential database systems that could be used?
I want to define a mapping of all common values of sy-dbsys in my coding, since I can generate native SQL on the fly depending on the db system.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable - you would need a time machine to get future DBs ;)

Answer (score 1):

The data element `DBSYS_TYPE_SELECTOR` refers to a domain of the same name which covers all possible values of `SY-DBSYS`. This is used in class `CL_DB_SYS`.

Comment: There are several domains, another is for example DBSYSTEM

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could do that. 
Just check the documentation on SY-DBSYS (including the domain definition) and you should find your list of possible DBMS.

Comment: the domain for DBSYS is just some CHAR (SYCHAR10 to be accurate) and doesn't contain a value list or a check table.